# RangeError in Flutter without exceeding Range

Tags: flutter, dart

I am modifying the basic "Send data to a new screen" example given in flutter cookbook [Link](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data) to add the passed data to hive database.
I am getting the error on tap of the list tile:
"The following IndexError was thrown while handling a gesture:
RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1000

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
Error: RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1000"

I looked up the error in [Link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RangeError-class.html) and found it is an issue with index crossing range. But i couldn't find where in my code the index is crossing range. What is the bug i am missing?

P.S. I need unique indice values greater than 1000 for hive database. Is this the issue?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

const String notesBoxName = "Notes";

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Note {
  @HiveField(0)
  String content;
  Note(this.content);
}

class Topic {
  int counteri;
  String title;
  Topic(this.counteri,this.title);
}

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter<Note>(NoteAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Note>(notesBoxName);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Notes Database',
    home: TopicsScreen(
      topics: List.generate(
        20,
        (i) => Topic(
          i,'Topic $i'
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class TopicsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Topic> topics;
  int indicep;
  String titlep;
  TopicsScreen({Key key, @required this.topics}) : super(key: key);
  int indicea = 0;
  
  void onSave() {
    Box<Note> notesBox = Hive.box<Note>(notesBoxName);
    indicea = 1000*indicep; 
    notesBox.putAt(indicea,Note(titlep));
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('3-Way Notes'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: topics.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                   title: Text(topics[index].title),
                   onTap: () {
                   titlep = topics[index].title; 
                   indicep = index;
                   onSave();
                   },
                 
                );
              },
            ),
         
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: It may come from this line : `notesBox.putAt(indicea,Note(titlep));`. Why did you multiply the index by 1000 ?

Comment: actually for the app i need the digits holding x,y,z coordinates as a number for eg. x=2,y=3,z=4..my indice would be 234..im still figuring out..but how do i fix the previous error? @AugustinR

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can copy paste run two full code below 
You can use `notesBox.put(indicea, Note(titlep));`  and get with `notesBox.get(indicea);`
You can not use `putAt` in your case, because `n-th key` still not exist

```
  // Associates the [value] with the n-th key. An exception is raised if the
  /// key does not exist.
  Future<void> putAt(int index, E value);
```

full code `main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'note.dart';

const String notesBoxName = "Notes";

class Topic {
  int counteri;
  String title;
  Topic(this.counteri, this.title);
}

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter<Note>(NoteAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Note>(notesBoxName);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Notes Database',
    home: TopicsScreen(
      topics: List.generate(
        20,
        (i) => Topic(i, 'Topic $i'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

class TopicsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Topic> topics;
  int indicep;
  String titlep;
  TopicsScreen({Key key, @required this.topics}) : super(key: key);
  int indicea = 0;

  void onSave() {
    Box<Note> notesBox = Hive.box<Note>(notesBoxName);
    indicea = 1000 * indicep;
    notesBox.put(indicea, Note(titlep));
    Note a = notesBox.get(indicea);
    print(a.content);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('3-Way Notes'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: topics.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(topics[index].title),
            onTap: () {
              titlep = topics[index].title;
              indicep = index;
              print("indicep $indicep");
              onSave();
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

full code `note.dart`

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'note.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Note {
  @HiveField(0)
  String content;
  Note(this.content);
}
```